# Why does Git not automatically fast forward?

Tags: git

When I do git pull, add, commit, push, this happens

```
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'http://foo:8080/tfsdev/foo/_git/Development.Services'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

when I add -ff to git pull, it goes through. 
I thought fastforward was default, why would this happen?

Comment: Are you sure no commits were added to the remote between pull and push?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> When I add -ff to git pull, it goes through. I thought fastforward was default, why would this happen?

You are mixing up a bunch of different concepts here ... which is no surprise, as `git pull` *also* mixed up a bunch of different concepts, in an attempt to be convenient that mostly results in being confusing.  (Well, also, occasionally convenient. :-) )

Using `git pull` does usually run `git merge`, which often does do a fast-forward instead of a merge.  This brings your branch up to date with whatever `git pull` brought over from the remote (via `git fetch`) so that commits you add, will also only *add to* (not replace or remove-from) their commits.  But `git push` is *not* the opposite of `git pull`, it's the opposite of `git fetch`: it *does not* do any merging.

When you do a `pull` + do stuff (commit or whatever) + `push` sequence, you are racing against other people who are also doing pull-commit-push sequences.  Whoever wins, gets to push.  This part really is that simple.  The problem comes in when you don't win!

*It's easy to win this race when you're the only one running.*  If no one else is pushing to that branch, you will always win the race.  What happened here is that you were not the only one running, and you lost.

The full answer is, unfortunately, complicated, and you did not show enough of what was going on to be able to answer this one specific case.  So let's take a look at what really happens.

## Always keep track of your current branch

If `git status` says `on branch master`, or `git branch` prints `* master`, your current branch is `master`.  Most Git commands work with your current branch, and `git pull` is no exception here.

The `git pull` command simply runs two other Git commands.  The first one is *always* `git fetch`.  The second one, you can change.

#### First, `git pull` runs `git fetch`

The first command `git pull` runs is `git fetch`.  It runs a *somewhat limited* `git fetch`, telling `git fetch` to bring over only as many commits and other items as are needed for your *current branch*.  If you just run `git fetch`, Git will bring over *everything*, which potentially takes a little bit longer, but means you're up to date with, well, everything.

The `git fetch` command is an exception to the usual Git rule about working with your current branch.  It does still look at your current branch in some cases, but what `git fetch` does normally is to update your *remote-tracking branches*.  In most cases you will have exactly one so-called *remote*, named `origin`, and running `git fetch` brings over everything from `origin` and updates your `origin/master`, `origin/develop`, and other `origin/` branches.  These are your remote-tracking branches for the remote named `origin`.

Hence, if you run `git fetch` yourself, it will update all your `origin/*` remote-tracking branches.  If you run `git pull`, it will run `git fetch` in a way that updates *only one* of these, based on your current branch.  These updates are always safe: they bring *new* commits into your repository, which have no effect on all the existing commits in your repository.

Just to be confusing, `git fetch` writes all its updates to a file named `FETCH_HEAD`, which you will see mentioned in [the `git fetch` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-fetch.html).  But it *also* updates your remote-tracking branches, unless you have a very old version of Git (older than Git version 1.8.4).  For those with ancient Gits (1.7.x), a manual `git fetch` of everything from `origin` updates them, but the one run by `git pull` doesn't.

#### Then `git pull` runs something else

Here things get a bit messy.  The *second* part of `git pull` is *either* `git merge` or `git rebase`.  The default is `git merge`, even though `git rebase` is often a better idea.  *You must choose in advance which command `git pull` should use.*  But which one *should* you use?  The only way to tell for sure is to look at what is coming in.  If you pick up the new commits, you can look at them with `git log` and other Git commands.

To see what's coming in, though, you have to bring it in.  That's what `git fetch` does.  The `git fetch` step brings in the new commits, *safely*, putting them safely behind those remote-tracking branches.  *Now* you can decide whether to merge or to rebase.

The `git pull` command makes you decide *before* you look.  So pick which one you want it to do—merge, or rebase—and pull, and it will fetch and then do that.  To make it do a rebase, run `git pull --rebase`, or set the current branch to make `git pull` do that by default.

(This setting is *per branch*, so you must set it for each branch.  There's also a configuration entry telling Git to set "rebase mode" automatically for each branch Git creates—but it's a lot easier, in my opinion, to just run `git fetch` yourself, and then run the second command yourself.  This gives you the chance to *look* at what you've fetched, as well as being a lot less confusing when things go wrong.)

## When the second command is `git merge`

Let's assume that the second thing `git pull` runs is `git merge`.  This *does* work on your current branch.  But `git merge` is itself somewhat complicated.

When you merge, you pick some commit—usually by a branch name, and very often by remote-tracking branch names like `origin/master`—and ask Git to figure out several things.  The *goal* of this merge is easy to state: **A merge combines work you did with work other people did, to make a new commit with both sets of work.**

To *figure out* what you did, and what they (whoever they are) did, Git has to find the *merge base*.  This merge base is, more or less, the first commit that you and they *share*.  This means it's time to draw part of a commit graph.  Here are some possibilities.

#### The fast-forward "merge"

```
...--o--*     <-- master
         \
          o   <-- origin/master
```

The `o`s represent commits, with newer commits towards the right.  I have marked the *merge base* commit with `*`.  Here, your `master` points to the merge base commit, with `origin/master` pointing to a newer commit.

In this case, `git merge` is able to do this "fast forward" thing.  That is, because the merge base already *is* the tip of `master`, there's no actual merging required.  Git can just slide the *name* master down-and-forward so that it points to the *same* commit as `origin/master`:

```
...--o--o
         \
          o   <-- master, origin/master
```

Now we can straighten out the line as well, and just have:

```
...--o--o--o  <-- master, origin/master
```

If you now run `git push origin master`, basically nothing happens, because there's nothing new on *your* end.  That last commit is one you *already got* from `origin`.

#### The real merge

But what if we have this instead?

```
...--o--*--o   <-- master
         \
          `-o    <-- origin/master
```

Here, Git has to do a *real* merge.  Git compares commit `*` to your `master` commit (the rightmost `o` on the top line), and to your `origin/master` commit (the `o` on the bottom line).  That is, Git runs `git diff` twice.  Then it tries to combine the two sets of changes and, if it succeeds, it makes a new commit, of the  "merge commit" flavor:

```
...--o--*--o--o   <-- master
         \   /
          `-o    <-- origin/master
```

This commit is ready to `git push` to `origin`, in a race against anyone else also trying to `git push` to `origin`.

#### Or maybe there's nothing at all to do

You could even have this to start with:

```
...--o--o--*   <-- master, origin/master
```

Now there's nothing for you to merge: the name `master` and the name `origin/master` both point to the same commit, so the merge base commit is already the tip of `master` (and of `origin/master` as well).  Now there's nothing to merge, and after doing nothing, there's nothing to push either.  You don't even have to attempt the race, much less win it.

## Now you can make new commits too

Now that your `master` and `origin/master` line up, you can make new commits.  When you do, *your* `master` will "get ahead of" `origin/master`:

```
...--o--o   o--o   <-- master
         \ /
          o   <-- origin/master
```

(I moved the bottom `o` down just so that I could point `origin/master` to it.)

## What `git push` does

I mentioned above that `push` is not the opposite of `pull`; it's more the opposite of `fetch`.

When you run `git push`, your Git calls up some other Git.  That's the Git on the remote `origin`, in this case.  It then hands over any new commits you've made, and a request: "please set your `master` to this latest commit."

In other words, we ask *their* Git to change *their* `master`–the thing *we* call `origin/master`—to match *our* `master`.

Look at those same drawings above.  When we did a fast-forward, we moved our `master` to a commit that we had already picked up from `origin/master`.  When we did nothing, we did nothing.  In either case, there *is no new commit*: there's nothing to bother pushing.  If we *do* push anyway, we'll say to the other Git: "There's nothing new here, but please set your `master` so that it points to this particular commit, just like ours does."

If we *did* make a new commit—as we did with the merge that really did something, or when we made new commits—we *do* have new stuff for them.  We'll hand them our new commits, then ask them to set their `master` the same as our `master`.

Of course, we'll be racing anyone else also pushing.

If no one else *has* won the push race, their `master` will still match our `origin/master`.  We'll ask to push, and—well, just look at that drawing above.  Moving `origin/master` (our name for their `master`) forward to match our `master`, why, that's one of those same fast-forward operations we saw earlier!

**If a push will do a fast-forward, it will generally succeed.**

But what if someone else won?  What if, after we ran `git fetch` and `git merge`, we spent some time making commits, and meanwhile someone else got in and pushed before us?

Well, now we have this:

```
...--o--o   o--o   <-- master
         \ /
          o   <-- origin/master
```

but that's not really quite right, because *they* have new commits on *their* `master`.  **They have the commits someone else pushed.**  We need to run `git fetch` and get them.  Let's do that, and *now*—now that `git fetch` updated our `origin/master` with the new commits—*now* we have:

```
...--o--o   o--o   <-- master
         \ /
          o-----o   <-- origin/master
```

Now, in order to push, we must either merge or rebase.  I'll draw the merge case.  (Note that the merge base is the left-most commit on the bottom line.)

```
...--o--o   o--o--o   <-- master
         \ /     /
          *-----o   <-- origin/master
```

If we make this merge, *now* we can push, because now our `master` is "fast-forward ahead of" their `master`.

Of course, while we're merging, we are also racing other people who might be trying to push.  If we lose the race, we may need to fetch and merge again.

(In all of these situations, `git rebase` is *probably* a better thing to do than `git merge`.  See other StackOverflow answers about rebase.)

Comment: Wow that is detailed! I'll need to read through a few times to fully process, but that did clear up some confusion.

Comment: Super answer! I'm going to need to read this a few times to fully grasp these concepts. thanks a lot!